# URL Rewrite - ISAPI

Tags: php, regex, windows, iis, url-rewriting

I have this URL http://www.example.com/controlpanel/index.php to be rewritten into the following:
http://www.example.com/

Meaning, I need to get rid of the "controlpanel" part somehow and force the index.php to resolve to root.

I am running Win Server 2016 & IIS 10.0.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you asking about ISAPI? IIS has had a managed-pipeline URL Rewrite module since IIS 7.

Comment: Well because this PHP app suggests that I should use either "Apache mod_rewrite" OR "Isapi rewrite". Thx

Comment: Be aware that PHP's documentation for IIS is very, very out of date (it still refers to IIS6 which was part of Windows Server 2003 - IIS7 is radically different and was released in 2006 with Windows Vista and Server 2008).

Comment: Sure thing. Btw could you help me with the issue even if it means using of URL Rewrite? Thx

Comment: Have you looked online for the IIS URL Rewrite documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do:

1. Install [IIS URL rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
2. Create web.config file with this content:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rewrite sample" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />           
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/controlpanel/index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you already have web.config file, just add my `rule`

This rule will rewrite your homepage `http://www.example.com/` to 
`http://www.example.com/controlpanel/index.php`

Comment: Hmm I don't think this will work for me. What I actually need is to rewrite the http://www.example.com/controlpanel/index.php to http://www.example.com/. In other words I want to hide (get rid of it) the portion controlpanel/index.php

Comment: It will do exactly what you want